# How do I completely uninstall Jruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, jruby

I recently installed Ruby on my Windows PC.
I also installed Jruby. After that I installed Rails using gems.
So when I tried to execute "rails server" on CMD an error would crop up saying "Cannot find JDK" or something like that. So I installed Jruby.
Now I get "Cannot find Jruby."

Can someone point out what I need to do?

[edit]
I want to be able to use rails normally, without all the hassle created by Jruby installation.

Comment: Did you install the JDK? And how did you install Jruby?

Comment: Yes. I did install the JRE/JDK from the website. I instaled Jruby using the installer from the website. I uninstalled it using the "Remove Program and Features" from control panel.

Comment: So after uninstalling it, it's still trying to use Jruby? Is it sticking around in your PATH, maybe? (`echo %PATH%` to check.)

Comment: No, I checked the path. No Jruby... I probably need to mess around with the registry. This is why I hate Windows :( Furthermore, it's not just adding the path is it? Did Jruby delete path to vanilla Ruby? This is insane.

Comment: Who knows? Try reinstalling Ruby and Rails. (And I doubt it's a registry thing. Linux -> Windows ports don't often use the registry.)

Comment: OK I got it. Easy way: I removed Jruby and then did a clean reinstall of Ruby and Rails as minitech suggested.
Thanks to everyone.
Expensive but better way: Get a Mac like all the Rails hipsters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you have some JRuby remnants in your `PATH` variable somewhere. if you checked your `PATH` then possibly a gem is installed as a JRuby gem or is locked as a JRuby gem in your bundle.

Possibly your RubyGems Environment is messed up. Try running `gem env` and look for anything out of the ordinary.

Anyway, try updating your bundle or checking your bundle's platform (`bundle platform`).

If neither of those work using `where.exe rails` will get you a match of all the `rails` batch files you can call from your `PATH` and you can debug it from there.

*Just a note: There shouldn't be anything you need to muck with in registry, most everything you might need is probably in your `environment variables`*

Comment: Oh, sound like this would have been easier but I already did a reinstall and gem Env looks normal now. Thanks though.